# Express Request second param from a different collection returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing a blog app and I want to render a specific blog post with:

```
router.get("/blog/:id",urlencodedParser, authCheck, (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.params.blog);
 res.render("blog", {user: req.user, blog: req.blog);
};
```

The console output gives me undefined and the page won't load.
Do I need to specify the blog somehow? 
I am just redirecting from the blog creation page, it should be processed and past with the post method (because the user is), or not?

Some sideinfo: 
 - NodeJS
 - Express
 - MongoDB
 - Two Collections: Users and Blog (both linked, but not implemented yet).

Thanks in advance for help.
Have a nice day whoever is reading this.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

You only got id as parameter so you have req.params.id

Answer (score 0):

You can only get from `req.params` the `id` variable because you define it in your url as "/blog/**:id**

To understand a little bit better about params you can [see de doc](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req).

About the render, you need to specify more so we can help you.

Comment: Basically the :id from the route should be a specific id from the database (blog collection).

And with the render I want to pass the user and the corresponding blog which I want to access via the id to the blog.ejs site.

Does that help?

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Did you put your blog collection into the "req.blog" to be accessed on your blog.ejs through `res.render("blog", {user: req.user, blog: req.blog);` as especified?

If not, this will be `undefined`, so everything you use like `blog.headline` will not work and could be the cause of your problem.